# manage site settings disabled in expression web

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser, expression-blend, expression-web

I  want to  check how my site is working with ie6, ie7. So I installed expression web (which comes with expression blend) ultimate version. After searching I found that i should configure site ---> site settings. But site settings is disabled in my expression web. Can any body help me with this. If possible can any one provide me with a link to tutorial to testing my sites on different IE versions and other browsers like fire fox, opera by using expression web. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you got Expression Web, you also got [SuperPreview](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/SuperPreview_Overview.aspx). SuperPreview is a great tool for comparing renderings of websites. You can have a base version and compare that in various ways with different other browsers. There's even a beta going on where a webpage is rendered online somewhere and shown as it would be renderen on Safari on a Mac for example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) program for the different IE version testing.